# Jquery Mobile Dialog - Full Width

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-ui-dialog

I am developing a website using Jquery Mobile
jquery.mobile- Version : 1.4.5
Jquery version         : 1.9.1

I am creating a dialog page using the following code

```
<div data-role="dialog" width="100vw" style="width:100vw;margin-left:0;margin-right:0;" data-close-btn="none" id="dlg" >
<div id="container" style="background-color:white;padding:5px;width:90vw;max-width:95vw;margin-left:0 !important;margin-right:0 !important;">
<h3>Task - Create</h3><hr>
<form data-ajax="false" id="form">
<label for="txtDescription">Description</label>
<input type="text" id="txtDescription" name="description">
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

The dialog div seems to be correctly sized to 100% of view port. Its left and top are also at 0,0
However the div with id '#container' is also sized to 90 and 05 % of viewport but it is not centered or positioned at 0,0. There is a large top and left margin because of which the #container is hidden on the right side. I want the #container to be positioned at 0,0

[image: Image showing the div #container. You can see the empty white space in the left and top.]

[image: Image showing the dialog Div. It is positioned at 0,0 and covers the entire viewport correctly.]

Comment: override the class `ui-dialog-contain`

Comment: @deblocker : Yes I have overridded the class ui-dialog-contain. Finally it works but with only !important.  .ui-dialog-contain {
 width: 92.5%;
 max-width: 1280px;
 margin: 0 0 0 0 !important;
 padding: 0;
 position: relative;
 top: -15px;
}